# Bringing devel and QA branches in sync in Mercurial: should I transplant?

Tags: mercurial

In our team we have a single repo with two branches: development and QA. QA was branched off at one point from development and acts as a frozen code branch. Only showstopper bugs that are fixed in the development branch are transplanted to the QA branch using HG transplant command.

What I am wondering is the following: after releasing a certain version, we need to bring the QA branch back into sync with the development branch. I am not sure that this would also be done using the transplant command? or is there a better (more proper) way/command to do that?

Comment: Wouldn't you just merge `QA` into `dev`?

Comment: Well, another QA cycle starts at that point whereas the development goes on. So we still need the QA branch, it just needs to be synched to a certain point in time with the dev branch. does that make sense?

Comment: Merging is your answer. All you're looking to do is pull down changes that were made in `QA` so `dev` has them. `QA` can continue to commit to their branch as they please, and you still have a full history if needed.

Comment: @JimmySawczuk: when you say merging, i imagine two heads/branches going into one which is not what we want. we want to keep the QA branch, just bring it up to date. Does merging allow that?

Comment: Just to clarify: after you merge one branch into another, you still have both, you can update to either and continue working. If, on the other hand, you want to stop working on the branch, you close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want to merge from the `dev` branch into the `qa` branch:

```
$ hg checkout qa # get to the QA branch
$ hg merge dev # merge in the dev branch
$ hg commit # and commit the merge
```

You might also want to consider using `hg tag` to tag versions after QA is done with them (for example, after the QA -> fix bugs - > QA -> ... -> QA approves cycle, you could use `hg tag qa-approved-2011-12-09` to mark the current revision as one QA approves of).

Comment: NOTE: reading through the comments, it seems like the QA branch is entirely transplanted from the dev branch. If this is true, my answer probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: that is exactly what we are doing, tags are the only commits specific to the QA branch. For any emergency packs, we can always branch off the QA tag... BTW, what is the difference between "hg up qa" and "hg checkout qa"?

Comment: only part of the DEV (critical bugfixes) are transplanted to QA so a merge is still needed. I think what you describe above should do what we need. Thanks! Just wondering the difference between "hg up qa" and "hg checkout qa"...

Comment: I'm a dumbass, "hg help checkout" reveals: "aliases: up, checkout, co". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your workflow, but you should merge development into QA (probably when you're going to freeze the next version).

If you made any commits in QA apart from transplanted ones, you'll better merge QA into development before doing dev -> QA merge.

Transplant if only good for cherry-picking.

Comment: We don't do any additional commits to the QA branch, everything is first commited to the DEV branch and then transplanted to QA. So what you are suggesting is merge QA back into DEV and branch of another QA from DEV again?

Comment: @Rok: If everything is committed to DEV, then, by definition, everything you have in QA is also in DEV. Hence, no need to do QA → DEV merge. Now to the second point. Why would you like to branch another QA? What is your workflow: do you want a permanent staging branch to work on "version next" (my guess), or multiple support branches for each version you release? In the first case, QA is a good name for staging branch. In the second, you better name each support branch v1.2, or 2.0-stable, or something like these.

Comment: The first one, we don't need multiple QA branches for supporting past releases, just one that is used to freeze and stabilize code at a certain point in time.